# A waterfall that's not as it seems to be

Tags: riddle

In Antarctica, a sight to see,

A waterfall that's not as it seems to be,

Its name might make you shiver and quiver,

But it's not blood, just a natural river.

What am I describing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a straightforward, non-obfuscated description and thus not really a puzzle.

Comment: voted to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably

> Blood Falls, a red-coloured waterfall in Antarctica. (It's not actual blood, obviously.)